# Finish the phrase: "Coincidence? or _________"

Tags: single-word-requests

Today I was wearing the same shirt as someone else, and we were paired together in a group project. I wanted to say the saying: "Coincidence? or ______" but I could not remember what word was supposed to go in the blank. Can someone help me?

Comment: You will need to provide a complete sentence here. The word you are looking for could differ, depending on the point you are making. For example "Coincidence or by design..." would suggest some possibility that the two had done it by arrangement. However "coincidence or the fact that it was St Patrick's Day..." might explain why you were both wearing a green shirt with a shamrock.

Comment: 'Coincidence or co-operation' are the alternatives, I would say.

Comment: I would more naturally say *by design* rather than any single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common phrases are "coincidence or fate", "Coincidence or destiny" and "coincidence or not". However, the most used is the "coincidence or fate". I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.